# Setting a float in NSObject throws doesNotRecognizeSelector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject, primitive-types, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I keep getting an error when trying to set the property of a `float`.

I have a `Download` class of `NSObject` that has a primitived `float`. The class is being called from `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` delegate method as the class downloads a file it needs to update the progress.

Though I keep getting an error `setProgress: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Any idea why?

**My Download NSObject class .h**

```
@interface Download : NSObject {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* url;  
@property (assign) float progress;
- (id) initWithUrl:(NSString*)url;

@end
```

**My Download NSObject class .m**

```
#import "Download.h"

@implementation Download

- (id) initWithUrl:(NSString*)url {
       if (self = [super init]) {
           self.url = url;
       }

    return self;

}
@end
```

**The method being called**

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
  {
 //OTHER STUFF

 Download * download = [[Download alloc] initWithUrl@"SomeUrl"];
 download.progress = (float)(totalBytesWritten)/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

}
```

**The Error**

> [__NSCFString setProgress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fbec1cbfee0
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setProgress:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbec1cbfee0' First throw
>   call stack:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation   __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw + 48
>
> 2   CoreFoundation    -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
>   + 205
>
> 3   CoreFoundation    *forwarding* + 970
>
> 4   CoreFoundation     _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>
> 5   DownloadManger   -[MainManagerViewController
>   URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]
>   + 420
>
> 6   CFNetwork         __113-[NSURLSession
>   delegate_downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
>   + 50
>
> 7   Foundation        _NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK_ +
>   7

Comment: Add `init with url` implementation code please...

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan I updated the question.

Comment: try using NSNumber instead of float, if it works then yoiu can convert nsnumber to float. @Firemarble

Comment: Don't have a `typedef NSString Download;` in there somewhere, do you?

Comment: No @Droppy I don't. What you see is what I have. I don't know what is up. It's very frustrating.

Comment: What about the missing `:` in `initWithUrl@"SomeUrl"`?

Comment: I think its a copy and paste / Stack Overflow formatting error. It's there.

Comment: I don't see how a copy and paste error can occur.  It doesn't give me confidence that what we are seeing is reality.

Comment: Let's see log output from this, run instead of setting progress... `Download * download = [[Download alloc] initWithUrl:@"SomeUrl"];  NSLog(@"%@", download);`

Answer (score 1):

Look in your MainManagerViewController.  You're sending setProgress to a NSString * not a Download object. Probably one of the parameters to MainManagerViewController URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite

Answer (score 0):

An error like that usually happens due to deallocation of your object. In your code sample the `Download` object is being deallocated right after you set the progress value on it. If you do not hold a strong reference to this object the pointer to it becomes invalid and therefore can point to any other object, in your case some random `NSString`.

```
Download * download = [[Download alloc] initWithUrl@"SomeUrl"];
download.progress = (float)(totalBytesWritten)/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

// Download object deallocated
```